# How do I load a file in GRUB as a bootloader?

Tags: boot, grub2

How do I load a file and execute it like a boot sector (load it at 0x07C0:0x0000 in real mode with the boot drive in DL) with GRUB 2?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the `i386-pc` platform version of GRUB 2, you can use the `chainloader` command. It can take either a filename, or blocklist notation, including `+1` to grab the first sector of the currently-selected partition.

If you are running some other platform version, like `x86_64-efi`, loading a BIOS-style boot sector is not possible. In general, chainloading means loading another bootloader through the same protocol that was used to load that particular version of GRUB. So with a `x86_64-efi` version of GRUB, you could chainload an EFI Shell or another `*.efi` binary file.